# How can I configure a custom build mode in vue cli 2 or make a build with development environment variables?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I need two build modes and in vue cli 3/4 the option is via `vue-cli-service build --mode staging` but I'm not able to find an alternative for vue cli 2.

Comment: Describe what you've already tried to do

Comment: @Gander I've tried adding a new build mode named staging in prod.env.js added an extra file named staging.env.js but found no way to link that in config also I've looked up for commands to build in development mode but didn't found any. I've tried adding an extra flag similar to cli 3 commands but that also doesn't work.